# Looking to use powershell to organize and separate files into folders based off of their names

Tags: powershell

I have a large amount of shows that I'm looking to organize based off of part of their filename. I would also like to have folders created for those shows if that's at all possible.
I have some basic understanding of Powershell, and don't really know how or where to start it. If you could also include and comments in anything you have/do create so that I can get a better understanding of what you did I would appreciate it.

Comment: So that is your idea of learning by being spoon fed? Sorry but [SO] is a site for programmers helping other programmers when they got stuck with a distinct problem not a script writing service. Don't expect others to put more effort in **your** task than you yourself.

Comment: Sorry if I offended or upset you, it wasn't the intent. I've been trying to learn what I could for the past couple weeks. I got excited when I saw how helpful people were here and figured I would ask. If you know any places I could go to start learning that were free other than reading up on sites such as this I wouldn't mind. Spoon fed wasn't what I was looking for per-say, I just figured I could see what was used and how to help me learn and apply in the future. But instead of getting suggestions on places to go to learn or even assistance you just want to attack people. Thanks I guess.

Comment: Show a [mcve] with sample input/expected output and point out what problems you have realizing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?
[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X704I79cN7Ugszg/JdVQL7fARF1HAUXQCCyoUKOgqlCtkJmmoKESr6Cbm1iSnKGgHqcRnahb5agbZaBrGautqYvKBWvUBOpSqjaojak2rAUJKCnopimo@IL0pxZHG8bqIDhGsQq1CrX//wMA)

```
'show-episode1.mp4', 'show-episode2.mp4' | % { if ($_ -match '^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+).mp4') { "{0}\{1}.mp4" -f $Matches[1], $Matches[2] } }
```

You can get your list of filenames with something like:

```
Get-ChildItem -Name
```

In the directory containing your shows.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I'll take this and move forward with it from here. I appreciate your help.